# When running Eclipse, I am getting a error in console after running the code

Tags: java, eclipse

So am literally taking a intro to Java Programming and now I am trying to create my second assignment. Upon doing so I have created the new java class within eclipse, but when I try to run the code that I have written, I am getting the following errors.

I am not real sure on how to fix this. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: math
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: math
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Comment: Lowercase _m_ looks kinda suspicious...

Comment: Without knowing what code you wrote and how you launch it, it's hard to help. What's sure is that you didn't respect two principles: always put classes inside a package, and respectthe Java naming conventions: classes start with an upper-case letter.

Comment: public class rounding {
public static void main (string[] args){
 System.outprintln("Hello World");

Comment: this is the code i tried to put in and well, it's not working - thank you so much JB for trying to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClassNotFoundException: math
I'm guessing you created a class with a capital M in math, but when you call it somewhere, it's not capitalized, or referenced properly. Try to double check that in your code.
Friendly FYI for proper Java standards, try to make sure that classes are capitalized.

Comment: where or how did i do this? maybe that's a rhetorical question, but I didn't do this when trying to start and create a new class

Comment: in eclipse's package explorer, double check that the class is Math with capital M. Assuming that's the case, look in any of your other classes for "math" with a lower case M. do this by pressing CTRL+F then find the word math, scope should be all, and select case senstive. Do this find in any of your other classes that use the Math class.

Comment: If you are dealing with multiple packages, make sure that you are referencing an import correctly, 
if the Math class is in a seperate package it would look like this
 `import packagename.Math;`

Comment: there is nothing found using ctrl +f. the funny thing, this worked great for me on sun and now kaput!! i've even gone so far as to deleting and reinstalling and that didn't work

Comment: I am bored enough to review your code. If you would like to, place it in a collabedit.com link, and share me your URL. I will continue to help there... But don't expect this kind of one on one from Stack overflow, this is only because I'm bored ;)

Comment: sorry didn't mean to post it that quick, i appreciate your assistance. for all involved, first I'm on a mac, isn't there a way to just purge the app and then reinstall? I tried this already but the old stuff is still there even after deleting and restarting

Comment: You can delete the project folder in the eclipse package explorer. And to get rid of everything and start from scratch, just make sure there's nothing in your workbench folder (Or wherever you decided to create the project).

Comment: well, i really don't know what i did, which is part of the problem, but in any case i got the hello world to work

Comment: is there a good recommendation for learning eclipse or for that matter being able to troubleshoot problems? I appreciate all of the help and thank you so much. BTW I fixed it by going through the tutorial again and did the hello world that way

Comment: Learning programming is challenging, but fun. If you need help with anything else, I'll be on [link](http://collabedit.com/rxqhj) for the next hour or so. Learning Java is the most important thing. The more you learn about Java, the more Eclipse will make sense. Trying to learn it the other way around will be challenging. There are several tutorials built in to eclipse to help you learn both the language and the software. To get these, go to Help menu then Welcome.

Comment: thanks "frantum" sending many beverages coffee or beer or both your way. :)

Answer (score 1):

You said your code is the following:

```
public class rounding {
    public static void main (string[] args){
        System.outprintln("Hello World");
```

From the error message you received, you most likely have this code in a file named `math.java`.  In Java, you must declare the class name as equal to the file name; for example, `YourClass.java` would declare `public class YourClass {`.

So what you need to do is either rename your class name to `math`, or name your file `rounding.java`, although it is unconventional to begin class names with a lower case letter.

On top of these errors however, you'll run into an error saying that the type `string` does not exist.  You need to rename that the type `string[]` to `String[]` or the JVM won't be able to identify your `main` method.

You will also receive an error saying that `outprintln` is not a method of the `System` class.  To print, use `System.out.println("Your message")` rather than `System.outprintln("Your message")`.

Comment: the file is saved by default in the test directory, I can't find any file or anything that says "math" other than the first error in the console

Comment: What is the name of the source file of your code, and what is the declared class name? These must be equal.

Comment: helloworld is the source file - helloworld is the declared class name

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to access a class called "math" that does not exist in your current project or scope. Did you forget to import a particular library that you're supposed to be using?

Comment: yeah, i saw that, don't know where that is coming from??

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code:

```
public class Rounding {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Some minor bugs which is usually done by all who start out with Java and Eclipse. The description of the error has already been given by Vulcan.